# How do I disable recentf-cleanup on exit?

Tags: hooks, recentf, exit

How do I disable recentf-cleanup on exit?

Setting `(setq recentf-auto-cleanup 'never)` is not enough.

Comment: `C-h v recentf-auto-cleanup` says `...Setting this variable directly does not take effect;
use M-x customize.` So try customizing it. If that still does not work, search your init file(s) for `recentf-cleanup`: you may be calling it somehow unwittingly. And try with `emacs -q`.

Comment: @NickD Ah, `doom` has `(add-hook 'kill-emacs-hook #'recentf-cleanup)`. :facepalms: Thanks!